# How to install immlib module in python?

Tags: python, debugging, python-2.x

I have Python 2.7 installed on my windows machine. I've downloaded and installed Immunity Debugger. But when I try to import immlib or immutils module in python, it says no such module. How to install these modules? 
Using pip, it says no such repository. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes with Immunity Debugger. Install immunity debugger and your immlib.py will be there.

Answer (score 2):

- Type "system settings" in the cortana/start bar search box
- Click "View Advanced System Settings
- In the Advanced tab in the bottom right corner click "Environment Variables"
- Create a new variable named "PYTHONPATH"
- Add these two directories to the PYTHONPATH variable:
- "C:\Program Files (x86)\Immunity Inc\Immunity Debugger"
- "C:\Program Files (x86)\Immunity Inc\Immunity Debugger\Libs"

Answer (score 1):

I am a Python and Immunity Debugger newbie, and to make the answer by @ArturKorobeynyk more crystal clear, what I had to do was:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:/Program Files (x86)/Immunity Inc/Immunity Debugger')
sys.path.append('C:/Program Files (x86)/Immunity Inc/Immunity Debugger/Libs')

import immlib
```